# Eslint configure for react

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am using eslint in a react project, I have .jsx, .js, .test.jsx, .test.js files, I want to configure my eslintrc.json file to such that, ,it check .js and .jsx files as well as ignore .test.jsx and .test.jsx file, how may I do that ?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `.eslintignore` file, to ignore certain folders and files.

Refer document: [ignoring-files-and-directories](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories)

> You can tell ESLint to ignore specific files and directories by creating an `.eslintignore` file in your project's root directory.
>   The `.eslintignore` file is a plain text file where each line is a glob pattern indicating which paths should be omitted from linting.

---

For example:

```
src/serviceWorker.ts
src/react-app-env.d.ts
```

Comment: but say i have folder
```
app-| 
       file.js
       file.test.js
```
then wouldn't adding the folder to .ignore would not be useful.

Comment: @sudiptdabral well you can make it `app/**/*.test.jsx`, for this issue, you can do it with no doubt, the only thing left is how to write it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @sudiptdabral It depends on your file structure description, you need to be more specific, maybe a screenshot of it.

Comment: I did add *.test.js in eslintignore file and it worked correctly ! thank you